# Saved instance state from parent class

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm working on an android app. I made a BottomBar design, which I have to put as a separate class for using it on all the activities. The problem is that I can't get the savedInstanceState when I call `bottomBar.attach()` from the activity that calls the bar (I get 'Cannot resolve symbol' error). Here's my code:

```java
public class bottom_bar extends AppCompatActivity {
    private BottomBar bottomBar;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    }

    private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;

    public void start() {
        coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        bottomBar = BottomBar.attach(this, savedInstanceState);
        bottomBar.setItemsFromMenu(R.menu.three_buttons_menu, new OnMenuTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            // Qué hacer cuando se aprieta cada botón de la barra.
            public void onMenuItemSelected(int itemId) {
                switch (itemId) {
                    case R.id.recent_item:
                        break;
                    case R.id.favorite_item:
                        break;
                    case R.id.location_item:
                        break;
                }
            }

            // Qué hacer cuando se aprieta de nuevo cada botón de la barra.
            public void onMenuTabReSelected(int itemId) {
                switch (itemId) {
                    case R.id.recent_item:
                        break;
                    case R.id.favorite_item:
                        break;
                    case R.id.location_item:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
        bottomBar.setActiveTabColor("#C2185B");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        // Necessary to restore the BottomBar's state, otherwise we would
        // lose the current tab on orientation change.
        bottomBar.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have a variable named `savedInstanceState`.

Comment: Post the call to `start()`